# OpenVPN left a SSL certificate... How to remove it?

Tags: server, openvpn, ssl, letsencrypt

Well a while ago I tried OpenVPN to use my server as VPN.
Then I wanted to get letsencrypt
then everything failed
then I removed OpenVPN
then the stupid certificate is still there

I have tried purging OpenSSL... Nothing

Help...

Comment: you might be somewhat better off on [sf]

Comment: Might put it there later

Comment: Put it there now :|